# New column based on all others in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am processing a excel file with a unknown number of columns, which may or may not be filled.

I want to create a new column in the dataframe which identifies which rows contains contain a 'nan' in **any** of the columns.

The `df`:

```
Col-1    Col-2  ...   Col-n    has_nans
ok       nan    ...   ok       true
ok       ok     ...   ok       false
ok       ok     ...   nan      true
```

I have tried may variations of:

```
df['res'] = df.iloc[:,2:].isna().all(axis=1)
```

to no avail.. Maybe a way would be using a lambda like [in here](https://datascientyst.com/highlight-nan-values-pandas-dataframe/)? Though I still couldn't quite figure out.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we should make sure 'nan' is `np.nan` , then change the function to `any`

```
#df = df.replace({'nan':np.nan})
df['res'] = df.iloc[:,2:].isna().any(axis=1)
```